# A field invariant with respect to vertical translations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying differential equations and there's an example that I am not understanding what is happening. It goes as follows:

**Example:** Assume that a continuous direction field on a plane maps into itself under all translations along a certain line and contains no directions parallel to that line.

[image: This is the picture in the book followed by the example.]

This picture is in the book which I am studying following the example.

**Question**: How exactly is the direction field mapped into itself? What does it mean to be mapped under all translations along a certain line and contains no directions parallel to that line?

If anyone could explain this example I would appreciate.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The direction field seems to have the property that you can move it vertically without changing it. Presumably we can move it any distance, though that is not obvious from the picture. And we don't see any vertical slope marks. So the line must be the $x$ axis or any other vertical line.

Comment: I see, the maps into itself means that we can map this solution to another one in the same vertical line via adding or subtracting a constant?